# Function only returns desired value once

Tags: python, function, file

I've created a script that will search a target file for a keyword. If that keyword is on a certain line of text, it will take the entire text and return the rest of the line not containing the keyword. For example, if there is a line of text that says:

```
Title: Useless Data
```

then the script will only take the part that says "useless data" and append it to a list. It will do this for every place in the file where the word "title" appears.

The script is successful if only run once to get several lines from the file and output them into a list, but I want to search the file for two key words: title and icon, and then zip the title to the corresponding icon. Thus, if I take a line of text that looks like this:

```
LINE 1:
Title: Useless Data
Icon: Fairly upset programmer
Index: 12
filler data:
LINE 2:
Title: Line 2
Icon: Pancho
Index: 69
filler data:
```

The output should be:

```
list1 = ['Useless Data', 'Line 2']
list2 = ['Fairly upset programmer', 'Pancho']
```

I then want to zip them into a dict that looks like this:

```
final_dict = {'Useless Data' : 'Line 2', 'Fairly upset programmer': 'Pancho'}

title_list = {}
target_file = open('Meta.txt', 'r')

# Searches for word in a line and removes all the useless data
def splitter(files, word):
    output = []
    for line in files:
        if word in line:
            output.append(line.split(':')[1].replace('\n', '').strip())
        else:
            continue
    print(output)
    return output

split1 = splitter(target_file, 'icon')
split2 = splitter(target_file, 'title')
final = zip(split1, split2)
```

Comment: You should use `for line in files.readlines():`

Comment: @Bazingaa: No, they should not.

Comment: what is wrong with the output? is the issue with the zip or your splitter function?

Comment: That "line of text" looks like **10** lines not one, so it's unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: Try `files.seek(0)` at the top of your `splitter` function. You are exhausting the file iterator object the first time you run through your function

Comment: To specify, it takes a file that contains several different lines and only searches for the line containing the specific word. The output only gives me one list containing the desired data and then an empty list when it should be giving me two lists so I can zip them.

Comment: P.S: Your file contains `Icon` and `Title` but you were checking with `icon` and `title`. Python strings are case sensitive

Comment: @Andromeda: I edited the final result to match what you want. Previous one was not consistent with your order of dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems in your code: First, you were using lowercase `icon` and `title` whereas your file contains uppercase `Icon` and `Title`. The strings are case sensitive in python so both are not identical. Second, after reading the contents of your file for the first call of function, the second time using `target_file` was not working for reasons specified by @roganjosh in the comments below. So you have two out of many other options: 1) Either read the file each time in the function or 2) use `files.seek(0)`. Both solutions are provided below.

```
title_list = {}

# Searches for word in a line and removes all the useless data
def splitter(word):
    target_file = open('Meta.txt', 'r')
    output = []
    for line in target_file:
        if word in line:
            output.append(line.split(':')[1].replace('\n', '').strip())
        else:
            continue

    target_file.close()
    return output

split1 = splitter('Icon')
split2 = splitter('Title')

final = dict([iter(split2), iter(split1)])
print (final)


{'Useless Data': 'Line 2', 'Fairly upset programmer': 'Pancho'}
```

Alternative solution suggested by @roganjosh using `files.seek(0)`

```
title_list = {}

target_file = 'Meta.txt'

# Searches for word in a line and removes all the useless data
def splitter(files, word):
    files.seek(0)
    output = []
    for line in target_file:
        if word in line:
            output.append(line.split(':')[1].replace('\n', '').strip())
        else:
            continue
    return output

with open(target_file) as infile:
    split1 = splitter(infile, 'Icon')
    split2 = splitter(infile, 'Title')
    final = dict([iter(split2), iter(split1)])
print (final)
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of your solution of opening the file in the function, I think it makes sense that the file object is passed as an argument for function reusability. Try my solution of `files.seek(0)` at the start of the function, and put `files` back in as an argument. I think that should work.

Comment: Could you add your solution as an edit to my question?

Comment: Since it's the same file object being passed to the function multiple times, after the first iteration through, you're now pointing to the end of the file so you can't read any further lines. Instead, you can reset back to the top.

Comment: Weirdly enough, adding target_file.seek(0) fixed the issue. Your solution also fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Andromeda please see my comment above yours to explain what's happening

Comment: Ok, I am adding roganjosh's suggestion to my answer

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh: You should use `infile` while calling the function, right?